# Swift MFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData JPG set max resolution

Tags: ios, swift, ios9

First of all, I'm new with Swift so sorry if I did something wrong.

I try to send an email with multiple images as attachment(s). But I can add all the images but they are at the full resolution.

Is it possible to limit the resolution of the images that are stored in an UIImage array? (now the email with 2 images will be 20MB instead 488KB)

Here some code:

```
    func configuredMailComposeViewController(image: [UIImage]) -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

        var counter = 1;
        for img in image {
            let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)!
            mailComposerVC.addAttachmentData(imageData, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "image\(counter).jpg")
            counter += 1
        }

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("subject")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("message", isHTML: true)

        return mailComposerVC
    }
```

And the images will be created here:

```
@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera

        presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    var image_taken: UIImage!
    image_taken = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    var image: UIImage!
    image = image_taken

    imageArray.append(image)

}


var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
```

And now call the createEmail method:

```
//send data to email
@IBAction func sendDataToServer(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    composeMail(imageArray)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use compression to reduce its size:

```
let imageData: NSData = (UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgView.image!, 0.5) as? NSData)!
mailComposer.addAttachmentData(imageData as Data, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "image.jpg")
```